# What's the best way to optimize a stored procedure with a table variable parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that accepts a table variable parameter. The table variable has a single column and is used to pass in a list of primary keys to query against.

The table variable definition is:

```
CREATE TYPE PrimaryKeyList AS TABLE
                              (
                                   PrimaryKey INT NOT NULL
                              )
```

The stored procedure definition is something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProc
    @idList AS PrimaryKeyList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id, col1, col2
    FROM myTable mt
    JOIN @idList ids ON ids.PrimaryKey = mt.id
END
```

The table `myTable` has several million rows and the stored procedure will encounter `PrimaryKeyLists` of varying lengths (between 1 and about 10,000).

How do I optimize the table variable structure and the stored procedure?

Would it make sense to add a clustered index to `PrimaryKeyList`? It will be reused elsewhere for the same purpose.

The `PrimaryKeyList` table variable is generated in C# as a `System.Data.DataTable` object and the stored procedure is invoked using ADO.

How would the performance differ between an indexed and non-indexed `PrimaryKeyList` table variable?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: The `TABLE` variable can morph into temporary table. You could create index this way: `DECLARE @x TABLE (id int, INDEX IX_id CLUSTERED(id));`

Answer (score 1):

Primary key in table variable will improve performance dramatically. No need to build it separately, you can use extended definition and it will be created as clustered by default (you can remove NOT NULL).
For sure it is expected to have clustered index on `myTable.id`, better primary key as well.

```
CREATE TYPE PrimaryKeyList AS TABLE(
    PrimaryKey INT PRIMARY KEY
)
```